# Adjust the behavior of a second class via a Context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

I have a class A and B.

B should work as a context manager, that changes A-s add operation result, like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount

    def __add__(self, other):
        # if context manager B() has set some value, add that value to sum
            #return self.amount + other.amount     + added_amount (from B)
        #else:
        return self.amount + other.amount


class B:
    def __init__(self, added_amount):    
        self.added_amount = added_amount

    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter method called')
        return self
     
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        print('exit method called')
```

I can only call it as:

```
with B(1000):
    a = A(1) + A(5)
    print(a)

Output: 1006
```

That means, I can't use keyword "as" like this: `with B(1000) as context:`, but I can change A-s behaviour.

Is it possible to do so?

Task is not practical, real life example, but purely theoretical.

Comment: Why can't you use `with B(1000) as context`?

Comment: Do you mean you wanna change the default function behavior of python?

Comment: @Ameya, it is possible, but just because you can it doesn't mean you should. And it is not a change of default function behaviour.

Comment: It is from some assignment and of course you should not do it in real project:) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a very ugly way to do what you want, by changing a class attribute in `A` that is copied locally every time an object is instantiated:

```py
class A:
    additional_amount = 0

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        self.local_additional_amount = A.additional_amount  # Remember the "context" at creation time

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.amount + other.amount + self.local_additional_amount


class B:
    def __init__(self, added_amount):
        self.added_amount = added_amount
        self.old_additional_amount = A.additional_amount  # Could be in `__enter__`, for a slightly different behaviour

    def __enter__(self):
        # Change the additional amount for A's created inside this context
        A.additional_amount = self.added_amount
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        # Restore As original amount, so we can nest it:
        A.additional_amount = self.old_additional_amount
```

This method makes your example pass, and can even use nested contexts:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test default behaviour:
    assert (A(2) + A(3)) == 5

    # Simple context (example requested by OP):
    with B(1000):
        assert (A(1) + A(5)) == 1006

    # Test default behaviour is restored:
    assert (A(1) + A(5)) == 6

    # Nested contexts work
    with B(1000):
        with B(2000):
            assert (A(1) + A(5)) == 2006
        # Out of the '2000' context
        assert (A(1) + A(5)) == 1006
    assert (A(1) + A(5)) == 6
```

Note that, in this implementation, the `context` is recorded at the time of creation, so you may get surprising behaviour:

```py
    with B(1000):
        a = A(1)
    with B(2000):
        b = A(1)
    assert (a + b) == 1002  # `a` adds 1000
    assert (b + a) == 2002  # but `b` adds 2000
```

It is possible to make every instance of `A` fetch the current context it is in, by using directly `A.additional_amount` in the `__add__` method.

In any case, *please*, never use it as anything more than a language puzzle. It is very surprising behaviour and goes against the Python philosophy of "Explicit is better than Implicit". As it uses essentially a global variable, it will break badly in any kind of concurrency or context switching cases (such as in a function that `yield`s from inside a `B` context).

As an aside, some languages implement a feature very similar to what you want. Have a look at [context parameters](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/using-clauses.html) in Scala, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved it using globals and that was even uglier. Also, thanks for the advice, it is purely theoretical question/puzzle from some assignment